# Can't read properties in Ethers library

Tags: javascript, typescript, solidity

I try to connect from WSL to Ganache but somehow i get this error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')`

ChatGPT says it's because you don't correctyl add ethers library or wrong import

so that is my import code
`const ethers = require("ethers");`  i also try that one too
`const { ethers } = require("ethers");`

and there is my json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ethers": "^6.9.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "fs-extra": "11.2.0",
    "ganache": "^7.9.2",
    "solc": "^0.8.7-fixed"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "yarn solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . -o . SimpleStorage.sol"
  }
}
```

I try to add librarry but code can't read it

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144451/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-jsonrpcprovider